ASP.NET Core & EF Core : concurrency exception not thrown despite working rowversion
This is part of my method which creates reservations of books:
var book = await _context.Books.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

if (book == null || !book.IsAvailable)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

var reservation = new Reservation
{
    BookId = book.Id,
    UserId = user.Id,
    ReservedAt = DateTime.Now,
    DueDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59),
    IsLease = false
};

book.IsAvailable = false;
var rv = Convert.FromBase64String(RowVersion);

_context.Entry(book).Property(b => b.RowVersion).OriginalValue = rv;

try
{
    _context.Reservations.Add(reservation);
    _context.Books.Update(book);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "Book already reserved by another user.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { searchTitle = searchTitle });
}

And the book model row version property:
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

I am trying to have concurrency handled here but the exception when the two users clicks reserve and call this method is never thrown. I have [Timestamp] attribute for row version in my Book model and I checked that it is actually changing every time it is updating the book. I also pass this row version from my view in a hidden field where i convert to string. I printed the logs and I see it is actually passed. I don't know what am I missing here, please help.
I also tried to include AsNoTracking as in Microsoft tutorial, but it did not change anything.

what happend with previous question? 79273210 ?

You won't get a conflict exception if there's no conflict with the database data. Trying to manufacture one by modifying tracker entities won't work, because the database data hasn't changed. context.Books.Update(book); is pointless by the way, as the entity is already tracked and book.IsAvailable = false; already modified it.

What does I am trying to have concurrency handled here mean anyway? Are you trying to implement concurrency for the web call? You already have optimistic concurrency at the EF/database layer. If some other user tries to modify the book between Books.FirstOrDefaultAsync and  SaveChangesAsync you'll get an exception automatically, without having to do anything.

To get concurrency at the API level, use the ETag header with a value guaranteed to change if the data changes, eg a checksum, a version number or the contents of rowversion. The client passes the original value with the If-Match header and your code compares it right after loading the book, when it already knows that the value has changed or not. If it has, it returns a 412 response.

Jeremy Likness explains how ETag's work and how they can be used for concurrency with rowversion etc

What database are you using? rowversion is a SQL Server type that isn't timebased and always changes if the row changes. In other databases you'll have to use other techniques. In MySQL even if you use ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) you still risk undetected conflicts if multiple saves happen in the same microsecond. Never mind what would happen with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP alone. In NpgSQL, xmin is quite similar to SQL Server's rowversion and so more robust

It seems the real question is how to implement optimistic concurrency at the API level, not the database. You get optimistic concurrency out of the box as far as the database is concerned, ie between the call to Books.FirstOrDefault and SaveChanges. DON'T USE AsNoTracking. Whatever tutorial you read, it was for a different thing.
Once you load the book you already know if the rowversion is different from the original or not. Instead of trying to get EF to throw, compare the values before doing anything else. if they don't match, return a 409 - Conflict error with ControllerBase.Conflict :
var book = await _context.Books.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

if (book == null || !book.IsAvailable)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

//Encode book.RowVersion into a string 
//instead of decoding RowVersion into bytes
var stored_rv = Convert.ToBase64String(book.RowVersion);
if(stored_rv!=RowVersion)
{
    return Conflict();
}

There's a standardized way in HTTP to check for version changes and conflicts through the ETag response header and If-Match and If-No-Match request headers. The web app fills the ETag response header with a value that's guaranteed to change if the data changes, eg a checksum or an item version.
In caching scenarios, clients send the ETag they received in the If-None-Match request header. Caches or web apps return new data only if the data has changed. If it hasn't, they return a 304 - Not Modified response to tell the client to use the data it already has.
In concurrency scenarios, the client sends the ETag in the If-Match header. If that doesn't match the server's value, a 412 - Precondition failed should be returned, although a 409 - Conflict is also valid.
Jeremy Likness explains how all this works in Five RESTFul Web Design Patterns Implemented in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Part 4: Optimistic Concurrency. The concepts are the same in all ASP.NET Core versions, even if the actual calls changed (for the better) in newer versions.
In the action that retrieves the Book, the rowversion is added as the ETag :
var etag=Convert.ToBase64String(book.RowVersion);
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ETag, etag);

In the reservation action, the IfMatch value is used to check for changes :
if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.IfMatch) &&
    HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.IfMatch].Contains(eTag))
{
    return Conflict();
}
...
//Send the new ETag to the client at the end
var etag=Convert.ToBase64String(book.RowVersion);
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ETag, etag);

In later ASP.NET Core versions you can bind action parameters to headers, eg :
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(...,
        [FromHeader(Name = "If-Match")] string? ifMatch,...)
{
...
}


Thanks for informative answer. Unfortunately, the first block of code you provided makes my application evealuate this if statement rv!=book.RowVersion to true everytime now when i reserve a book
even when there is no conflict.

Fixed it. I had copied the original code and ended up with a reference equality between two byte[] arrays. Now I use Convert.ToBase64String(book.RowVersion) to get a string from the book and compare it to the tag/token

It did not help. Now the conflict never occures.

That would only happen if the rowversion hasn't changed. In which case there's no conflict. You never posted how RowVersion is created so I assumed it's provided by the client. If not, where does this come from? Is it different from the book.RowVersion loaded by the first query?

PS: what does Now the conflict never occurs mean? That there was no exception? That's the whole point, you don't need that exception. If you want to redirect instead of returning a Conflict result, go ahead and call return RedirectToAction("Index", new { searchTitle = searchTitle }); instead of return Conflict();

I'll try to be more precise. By conflict I mean this situation: John goes to the index view which lists all the books for him. Then Mary also visits index view and she is faster than John and clicks reserve. Then John clicks reserve to reserve the same book. Reservation belongs to Mary but I want to inform (ideally display some message) John that someone was faster that him and he did not make a reservation. My index view has list of the books so I pass in the hidden field book.RowVersion converted to string to reserve method.

That's not a concurrency conflict at all. That's normal business processing. Check the availability before proceeding. What you describe in the comment isn't related to the question at all. The only case for a database concurrency conflict would be if both users executed Reserve at the same time, in which case they'd try to save the Book at the same time. If you're using SQL Server and the Book table has a rowversion column, the database itself will change the rowversion if the row changes, resulting in a concurrency exception. rowversion is a database feature, not an EF feature
